# displaying two name underneath each other after the logo

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to display a logo and right next to the logo, I want to display the name of the parent company and then the name of my company right underneath the parent company in a HTML page. when I browse the HTML page, I see the name of the parent company, but I don't see the name of my company. I have the following code:

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <span style="display:flex;">
            <a href="https://www.apple.com/">
                <img src="Images/apple.png" alt="RCA" width="80" height="80" class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2" runat="server" />
            </a>
            <span style="font-size:25px;color:white;"><span style="color:#e9c46a">This is parent Company</span><br />This is my company name</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

I dont see "This is my company name" right underneath the parent company. I want both "This is parent Company" and "This is my company name" aligned in the middle right underneath each other. Right now, when I run the code, I see this:

[image]

I want something like this:

```
logo This is parent Company
     This is my company name
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        
        .logo {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }
        
        .names {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        
        .name {
            font-size: 24px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="names">
            <div class="name">Parent Company</div>
            <div class="name">My Company</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just add your logo and make any necessary adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this help you:

```css
.test {
    padding-left: 110px;
}

.test1 {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align:left;
}

.test2 {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="test1">
            <a href="https://www.apple.com/">
            <img width="100px" height="100px" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png"/></a>
            <span class="test2"> This is parent Company</span> 
        </div>
        <div class="test">
            <span>This is my company name</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```